# How to create pointcut to feign client that supports interface inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-cloud-feign, pointcut

In a Spring Boot project I have a simple feign client

```java
@MyAnnotation
@FeignClient(name="some-name", url="http://test.url")
public interface MyClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/endpoint")
    List<Store> getSomething();
}
```

I need to intercept all calls and for this and I'm creating a common library that can be used in different projects. To achieve it I try to use Spring AOP. I created an aspect that wraps all public methods of the object annotated with `MyAnnotation`

```java
@Around("@within(MyAnnotation) && execution(public * *(..))")
public Object myWrapper(ProceedingJoinPoint invocation) throws Throwable {
   // ...
}
```

It works correctly and all calls are intercepted till I tried to put `MyAnnotation` on the feign client that uses inheritance for feign interfaces. When I init my client with inherited interface calls are not intercepted anymore.

```java
public interface FeignClientInterface {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/endpoint")
    List<Store> getSomething();
}

@MyAnnotation
@FeignClient(name="some-name", url="http://test.url")
public interface MyClient extends FeignClientInterface{ 
}
```

I tried:

- `"@target(MyAnnotation) && execution(public * *(..))"` but when I connected my library to the real project I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages` It seems that it wanted to wrap all to the proxy and there were final classes.
- `"@target(MyAnnotation) && execution(public * com.my.company.base.package.*(..))"` removed previous issue but gave another one, like some bean cannot be instantiated without name, etc.

The question is how to make it work without moving `@MyAnnotation` to the base interface `FeignClientInterface`. It is in another project and I don't have a control on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after hours of investigation I replaced my pointcut with this one

```java
@Around("execution(* (@MyAnnotation *).*(..)) || execution(@MyAnnotation * *(..))")
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452483/3457177) I used only `execution` to avoid proxy creation.

Comment: Good that you found the solution . Out of curiosity I have been trying to debug this issue. Could you please check and let me know if the following pointcut resolves the issue for you ? `(@target(MyAnnotation) && within(com.my.company.base.package..*))`. I could reproduce your issue with `@target` alone , but it goes off when I introduce the scoping designator `within`.

Comment: I tried this and this can work if you don't have final classes or other proxies in `com.my.company.base.package`. I needed to include it in a big project and and when I did it I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.Slf4jScopeDecorator` 
But this worked perfectly in my library and created unit tests were all successfull

Comment: As far as I understood, when we use `@target` Spring creates a proxies for all possible beans. In  a big project there were some final classes, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tried to recreate the case with a final class within the scope and adding `within()` to the pointcut tend to resolve the issue . Yours is a real project and the complexity would be definitely higher.

Comment: Yes, it will work for 99% of cases but I got a chance to fall into 1% :) Final beans, feign clients, some other aspects, a lot of other stuff I'm not familiar with inside the project. Thanks for trying to help anyway :)