# spring aop @target and @within throw IllegalAccessError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

**when run the application, it throws IllegalAccessError，Application run failed**

here is demo aop、service、annotation used，a simple annotation and @Before advice，also enable @EnableAspectJAutoProxy

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MethodInterceptAnnotation {
}

@Component
@Aspect
public class MethodInterceptAop {
    @Before("@target(com.example.demo.aop.MethodInterceptAnnotation)")
    public void beforeCheck() {
        System.out.println("before check");
    }
}

public interface UserService {
    String getUserName(int a);
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @MethodInterceptAnnotation
    public String getUserName(int age) {
        System.out.println("age:" + age);
        return age + "";
    }
}
```

change`@target` to `@within` error again, 
but change`@target` to `@annotation` everything is ok

here is partial stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError-->class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5c9e457 cannot access its superclass org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:538) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5c9e457 cannot access its superclass org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:535) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

anyone know what is wrong with this code, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using devtools ?

Comment: Yes. spring-boot-devtools in pom.xml, does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation : [Supported Pointcut Designators](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

> @target: Limits matching to join points (the execution of methods when
>   using Spring AOP) where the class of the executing object has an
>   annotation of the given type.
>
> @within: Limits matching to join points within types that have the
>   given annotation (the execution of methods declared in types with the
>   given annotation when using Spring AOP).

Both `@target` and `@within` advice types are for the class/type .

The scope of the pointcut is global and when the application starts up it tries to identify all the classes/types with annotation and interferes with unwanted classes , here `EmbeddedTomcat` related.

For `@target` and `@within` advice types to work , try narrowing the scope by adding a scoping designator as follows

`@Before("@target(com.example.demo.aop.MethodInterceptAnnotation) && within(com.example.demo..*)")`

For me , narrowing the scope have always worked , but have come across SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61412906/4214241) where that too did not help. In that case , resolution for your issue is available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452483/4214241) from @kriegaex.

Please go through the answer and comments to understand the difference when `@annotation` is used. To summarize , advice types `@target` and `@within` when used , tends to create proxies for all classes irrespective if the annotation is present or not at class level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: narrowing the scope and move annotation to class level did work.@target @within can not be used on method level?

Comment: @code1234 those advice types are intended for type level annotations. It cannot be used to target method annotations. For that you need to use `@annotation`