# Spring Boot 2 after aop annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to create a @after aop annotation to execute a code after the method got completed. I am facing issues when I pass with parameter.

Aspect Code -

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class FinalAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(finalEvent)")
    public void runFinalMethod() {}

    @After("runFinalMethod()")
    public void finalMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, FinalEvent finalEvent) throws Throwable { 
       ....
    }
}
```

FinalEvent -

```
@Target({ElementType.Method})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FinalEvent {
   String value() default "";
}
```

Controller -

```
@FinalEvent(value = "test")
public ResponseEntity<String> getDetails() { ... }
```

This throws error:

> error Type referred to is not an annotation type: finalEvent

But if I remove the "value" property from FinalEvent interface and change to @annotation(**F**inalEvent), it works. But I need to pass parameter.

If I modify to @Pointcut("@annotation(com.aspect.finalEvent)") then it throws error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Following code would work

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class FinalAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(finalEvent) && within(so.qn68380528.service..*)")
    public void runFinalMethod(FinalEvent finalEvent) {}

    @After("runFinalMethod(finalEvent)")
    public void finalMethod(FinalEvent finalEvent) throws Throwable { 
       System.out.println(finalEvent.value());
    }
}
```

Remember to limit the scope : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#writing-good-pointcuts

You may also go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452483/4214241) from @kriegaex to understand why an `@annotation` has a global scope.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and modified the answer.